# Coordinator Layout & App Bar Layout Performance

Tags: android, performance, layout, android-coordinatorlayout

I'm using the relatively new `CoordinatorLayout`, along with `AppBarLayout` and `Toolbar`.  The layout is quite simple and the behaviour of the layout is to 'hide' the `Toolbar` when scrolling up and when scrolling down show the `Toolbar`.

The XML for the layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:id="@+id/main_content_coordinate_layout"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/main_content_app_bar_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/action_bar_height"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/main_content_toolbar_layout"
            app:title="@string/app_name"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/main_content_app_bar_layout"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/main_content_media_navigation_recycler_view"
            android:padding="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin_0.50"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/action_bar_height"/>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/main_content_container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**The Problem**

I'm seeing a CPU performance hit of about 10-15% when the `Toolbar` is visible, but when scrolling and the `Toolbar` has scrolled off the screen, or visually to that effect, this drops to 0-1%.  I have removed the Child `CoordinatorLayout` Items (`RecyclerView` & `FrameLayout`), but this still continues.  Also I have tried altering the behaviours of the `AppBarLayout` and `Toolbar`, this also has no effect.

The image below demonstrates CPU performance when Toolbar is visible, then invisible.

[image: Image showing CPU performance]

I know that `CoordinatorLayout` and behaviours require extra processing and cpu cycles, but this seems excessive.  Has other people experienced this sort of performance hit using `CoordinatorLayout`, `AppbarLayout` and `Toolbar` together?

*Extra Info*

These CPU figures were taken from a OnePlus 3, so a higher specced phone, my obvious worry is performance on mid to low end devices (at present I don't have any to test on, and emulator testing won't cut it for this purpose).

Comment: Same on Xperia Z3c, also around 10 to 14 percent un User processes.